# Select results with only 2 types of products

Tags: sql

I need to receive claims (of a customer) who has only specific types of products (productid IN(1,2)). There are different other products but I need only the ones with type 1 and 2 (who would have both at the same time). Client might have other products as well but important to take the ones who have 1&2

Example

```
clientID claimID productID
 123       333      1
 123       333      2
 123       333      4
 123       333      6
 123       333      7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT C.clientID
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS C
WHERE C.productID IN(1,2)
GROUP BY C.clientID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C.productID)=2
```

Comment: This will just return the client IDs, not the claims themselves.

Comment: SELECT C.claimID
FROM CTE AS C
WHERE C.productID IN(1,2)
GROUP BY C.claimID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C.productID)=2

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
It worked as expected, appreciate your help

Comment: Won't that second one only return *claims* that involve both products, not *all claims for a customer* who has *any claims* involving those products?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (not necessarily prettiest) way to do this is:

```sql
SELECT c1.*
FROM claims c1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT c2.*
    FROM claims c2
    WHERE c2.productID IN (1, 2)
    AND c2.clientID = c1.clientID
)
```

In other words, select each claim `c1` where there is at least one claim `c2` that has the same `clientID` as `c1`, and a `productID` of `1` or `2`.